# Need help converting a pine v2 script to pine v4

Tags: pine-script

I am trying to convert a pine script from v2 to v4 but having issues understanding what i am doing wrong and getting the below errors. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank You..

line 10: Undeclared identifier `vqi_t`;
line 11: Undeclared identifier `vqi_t`;
line 12: Undeclared identifier `vqi`;
line 13: Undeclared identifier `vqi_sum`;
line 14: Undeclared identifier `vqi_sum`;
line 15: Undeclared identifier `vqi_sum`;
line 19: Undeclared identifier `vqi_sum`;

```
length_slow=input(9, title="Fast EMA Length")
length_fast=input(200, title="Slow EMA Length")

vqi_t=iff((tr != 0) and ((high - low) != 0) ,(((close-close[1])/tr)+((close-open)/(high-low)))*0.5,nz(vqi_t[1]))

vqi = abs(vqi_t) * ((close - close[1] + (close - open)) * 0.5)
vqi_sum=cum(vqi)
plot(vqi_sum, color=red, linewidth=2)
plot(sma(vqi_sum,length_slow), color=green, linewidth=2)
plot(sma(vqi_sum,length_fast),color=orange, linewidth=2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Pine v2, while declaring a variable, you could reference a past value of that variable. This was removed in Pine v3. To work around this and make code that will compile in v3, you need to declare this variable as `na` first, and then assign it a new value with the `:=` operator:

```
vqi_t = na
vqi_t := iff((tr != 0) and ((high - low) != 0) ,(((close-close[1])/tr)+((close-open)/(high-low)))*0.5,nz(vqi_t[1]))
```

Note: that code is only valid for Pine v3; in v4, you'd have to use `float vqi_t = na` instead. That being said, the best course of action is to convert v2 -> v3 manually and then use the built-in Pine converter to automatically convert v3 -> v4, it will handle everything for you.

Comment: This was rather simple, but i wasn't aware of this. Thank you so much for pointing out the issue. I was able to convert the pine script to v4. Your the best!!